# Lazy initialization Singleton class with volatile variable

Tags: java, design-patterns

I came across a singleton class {lazy initialization}. The code is as below

```
// Singleton reference for this class
    private static volatile FileProperties INSTANCE = null; 

    public static FileProperties getInstance() {
            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                synchronized (FileProperties.class) {
                    if (INSTANCE == null) {
                        INSTANCE = new FileProperties();
                    }
                }
            }
            return INSTANCE;
        }
```

My question is what is the benefit we are getting by making **INSTANCE as volatile**
Since we already taking care of thread safety by synchronized.
Is there any benefit of volatile in this scenario ?

Comment: See http://jeremymanson.blogspot.co.uk/2008/05/double-checked-locking.html

Comment: This double checked locking has a potential error, in that the INSTANCE variable may be assigned a non-null value, *before* the constructor of FileProperties has fully executed. This doesn't matter if the constructor is empty, of course.

Comment: @JakobJenkov maybe worth clarifying: **IF** INSTANCE is not volatile.

Comment: Consider adding the private Contructor too for the code above.

Answer (score 5):

That is because double-checked locking without `volatile` is not thread-safe in Java.

The simplest way to make thread-safe lazy-init singleton is to create class holder as follows:

```
public class SomeClass {
    private static class SomeClassHolder {
        public static final SomeClass INSTANCE = new SomeClass();
    }

    public static SomeClass getInstance() {
       return SomeClassHolder.INSTANCE;
    } 

    private SomeClass() {}

}
```

That part of code, because of JVM behavior will load SomeClassHolder and create an instance of SomeClass on first usage of `getInstance()` (and not when SomeClass is loaded by classloader).

You don't need to use any synchronization at all!! Because JVM is doing it for you.

Comment: double checked locking has been threadsafe since the introduction of "happens before" implication of `volatile` (Java 1.5). Also, you're missing a private constructor

Comment: DCL *is* thread-safe in Java from Java 1.5 onwards, so long as you *also* use `volatile`. (I wouldn't use it myself, but it's thread-safe.)

Comment: @Bohemian: `volatile` was in Java from 1.0, I believe. Properly-implemented DCL has been thread-safe since the memory model changes in 1.5.

Comment: Thanks guys, but not without a keyword `volatile` and that is what the answer was about.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yep, you're right. From 1.5 onwards, "happens before" was enforced. Cheers.

Comment: @MichalBorek: The answer doesn't state that at all - it doesn't even *mention* the word `volatile`, and it refers to an article referring to an old version of the memory model.